# Laravel 504 Gateway Timeout if APP_ENV is not local under nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, timeout, amazon-elb

I am facing a strange error. We moved our Laravel 8 app from apache2 to nginx under Aws ELB load balancer. Now the problem is, if my APP_ENV value is production/testing, I am not able to log in to my app it shows 504 gateway timeout but if I change my APP_ENV to local, it is working fine.

I tested this multiple times but faced the same result. Can anyone help me out with this? TIA

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe this issue comes from Nginx or your config for php-fpm, did you test it? which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: I am using PHP7.4, I never faced this issue and its really strange it works well with APP_ENV local but not production

Comment: if you can show us your Nginx config file, maybe you have differ configuration for production and different for the dev env

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which you can set the timeout for php-fpm. In /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf I added this line request_terminate_timeout = 180
location ~ .php$ {fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;fastcgi_read_timeout 180;include fastcgi_params;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Aws ELB load balancer timeout setting because
php timeout setting can't override load balancer timeout setting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).